# Definition of Irreducible Graded $Z_2$ Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-modules

I am reading Dale. Husemoller's Fiber Bundles where he defines graded modules over a graded algebra as follows.[image]

Next, he talks about irreducible graded modules in the lines given below.[image]

Now, I don't get it, How can an Irreducible graded Module be defined as it should not have any submodules. But graded implies the existence of $M^0 , M^1$.

I think I may have misinterpreted something. Kindly help!.

regards

Comment: You will get a better answer (and you may even answer your own question!) if you explain why you think the existence of $M^0$ and $M^1$ contradicts irreducibility.

Comment: @MatthewTowers Aren't M^0 and M^1 are submodules of M, Z_2 grading is about decomposing the given module as the direct sum of  two submodules If am not wrong?

Comment: not A-submodules, no - how could they be, when the definition requires $A^1M^0 \subseteq M^1$?

Comment: Oh, interesting then what are these M0 and M1 just any two subsets & if they  are not submodules how can their direct  sum be  defined and is a module? @MatthewTowers